# WKT desktop viewer and SQL query on ODBC database

Tags: maps, sql, gis

I have a proprietary database that supports SQL and has ODBC driver to connect to.
it has geography columns stored in WKT format.
Is there a free desktop application that I can use to connect and query and display the geometry?
I tried ArcGIS desktop, or FME, but they both work on specific databases (Oracle, Sql Server...), and I need an application that supports only ODBC and SQL.

Comment: You should try the DB2 connection through QGIS, and failing that, QGIS also has a 'QuickWKT' plugin that allows you to copy/paste WKT from your database and plot it on the map - not actually connected to the database, but at least you have a quick way to view features.

Comment: ODBC is supported in QGIS. See the [doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html) or this similar [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/reading-odbc-connection-using-qgis) (for the connection part)